# Find the probability of sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ be two independent random variables, while $a_1$ and $a_2$ are some deterministic variables in $D\subset \mathbb{R}$.
We are given that for each $i$ there exists $b_i$, such that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[ |a_i - \varepsilon_i| \leq b_i\right] \geq 1-\delta_i
$$
for some $\delta_i \geq 0$.

Find aprobability $\bar{\delta}$, so that
$$\mathbb{P}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{2} |a_i - \varepsilon_i| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{2} b_i\right] \geq 1-\bar{\delta}.$$

I tried using the Boole's inequality, but failed to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbb{P}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{2} |a_i - \varepsilon_i| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{2} b_i\right] \geq \mathbb{P}\left[|a_1 - \varepsilon_1| \leq \ b_1\right] \mathbb{P}\left[|a_1 - \varepsilon_1| \leq \ b_1\right] \geq (1-\delta_1)(1-\delta_2) =1-\bar{\delta}.$$ if
$\overline {\delta} =\delta_1+\delta_2-\delta_1\delta_2$.

Comment: How do you get the first inequality?

Comment: If $|a_1-\epsilon_1| \leq b_1$ and $|a_2-\epsilon_2| \leq b_1$ then  $|a_1-\epsilon_1| +|a_2-\epsilon_2| \leq b_1+b_2$. Also, the probability that $|a_1-\epsilon_1| \leq b_1$ and $|a_2-\epsilon_2| \leq b_1$  becomes a product by independence.  @Seda